# Undo not working on 2.74

Tags: shortcut, versions

my undo does not work on 2.74, but it does work perfectly on 2.73 and older.
If I change keymapping from ctrl + z to something else, it still doesn't work.

Operating system is Win 7

Thank you for you help!

Tapio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have set the undo steps to Zero in the User Preferences :

go to : **User Preferences**➜**Editing**➜ **Undo**➜ **Steps**  and set it to some number ( default 32 ) then save the settings

[image]

Comment: Hi and thank you. I do have that set on 128, so it is not that one.

Comment: @Tapio restore the default key layout and try again

Comment: I loaded factory defaults and that helped! Thank you for your help!